# Camera Module take pictures every 30 sec to SD card

Tags: sd-card, camera

I have the camera module for the raspberry pi. I need to know, how do I program the pi to take an image every 30 seconds and save the images to the inserted 64gb SD card.

Comment: There are atleast 10 ways to do this if not 101 ways. Are you using the desktop? You want to write a script, program? raspicam has a timelapse feature and motion also but there are so many other ways. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

You could just use the raspistill's built in timelapse option:

```
raspistill -t 30000 -tl 2000 -o image%04d.jpg
```

That will take a picture every 2 seconds over a total period of 30 seconds with the files named image1.jpg, image0002.jpg...image0015.jpg. The %04d will be changed into a four-digit number with leading zeros added. I.e. %08d would give you an eight-digit number.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a bash script and cron job.

Create a bash script inside `/home/pi` directory using your favourite text editor and name it `takephoto.sh` for example.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
raspistill -o /home/pi/stills/$DATE.jpg
```

Then when you saved it you need to set the execute flag on the file with the following command.

```
chmod +x takephoto.sh
```

Create a directory, like `/home/pi/stills`, the same as in the bash script. Now from `/home/pi` you can test the script by executing it using `./takephoto.sh`

You should have an image created inside the still folder with the timestamp.

Now you can [setup a cron job](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27361/894) to execute the script with the interval you require.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. This pi setup is going in a weather balloon to take images, saved to sd card. The pi will be powered by a lipo battery. I want to take the sd card out of the pi and upload them to my desktop.

Comment: crons minimum resolution is 1 minute so probably simplest to just have a sleep(30) and loop the script continuously.